# How to replace a column name with another column value in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to write a pyspark SQL code that converts the below data frame into the mentioned dataframe.
Basically, it renames the Value column based on the Lang column value.

However unable to get this converted, Can someone help

Dataframe

| ID | Lang | Value | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | GE | LUX-GE-BEL | BEL |
| D1 | NL | LUX-NL-BEL | BEL |
| D1 | FR | LUX-FR-GER | GER |
| D2 | GE | LUX-GE-BEL | BEL |
| D2 | PE | LUX-PE-GER | GER |

Concerted Dataframe

| ID | Value-GE | Value-NL | Value-FR | Value-PE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | LUX-GE-BEL | LUX-NL-BEL | LUX-FR-GER | - |
| D2 | LUX-GE-BEL | - | - | LUX-PE-GER |

Using withColumnRenamed didn't work out a it's about dynamically creating the column name from the values of another column

Comment: First extract the unique column name values. Then create the column names using foldleft.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck? We shouldn't write all your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

By pivoting and changing col name according to your requirements you can achieve your desired output
code:-

```html
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DynamicPivot").getOrCreate()
data = [
    ("D1", "GE", "LUX-GE-BEL", "BEL"),
    ("D1", "NL", "LUX-NL-BEL", "BEL"),
    ("D1", "FR", "LUX-FR-GER", "GER"),
    ("D2", "GE", "LUX-GE-BEL", "BEL"),
    ("D2", "PE", "LUX-PE-GER", "GER")
]
columns = ["ID", "Lang", "Value", "Region"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.show()

# Pivot the data using pivot function
pivot_data = df.groupBy("ID").pivot("Lang").agg(expr("first(Value)"))
pivot_data.show()
for col_name in pivot_data.columns[1:]:
          pivot_data = pivot_data.withColumn(col_name + '_value',col(col_name))
          pivot_data=pivot_data.drop(col_name)
pivot_data.show()
```

[image]

ACCEPT THIS ANSWER IF IT FULFILLED YOUR REQUIREMENTS